# Botão submit fechando modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, login

Olá!
Criei uma modal para chamar os inputs de login.
Porém quando clico em "Login" no botão submit, caso esteja vazio ou com informações incorretas, ele fecha a modal e não me exibe mensagem de erro como esperado...
Eu estou começando a aprender php e javascript, então não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço!

Código que estou utilizando na minha index.php para chamar a modal:

```
    <!-- Trigger button do modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginmodal">Login</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginlabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginlabel">Login</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <?php include 'loginform.php';?> <!-- Aqui vc chama a sua página -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Minha página de login "loginform.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['nao_autenticado'])):
                    ?>
                    <div class="notification is-danger">
                      <p>ERRO: Usuário ou senha inválidos.</p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    unset($_SESSION['nao_autenticado']);
                    
?>
<div class="box">
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input name="usuario" name="text" class="input is-large" placeholder="Seu usuário" autofocus="">
            </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input name="senha" class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Sua senha">
            </div>
        </div>
        



        <button type="submit" name="login" class="button btn btn-secondary" >Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>        


    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que a modal apenas fecha quando tem alguma informação de login incorreta. Quando dá certo ele me redireciona para a página desejada.
Depois de dar submit e abrir a modal outra vez, o erro está lá aparecendo...

Comment: Esqueceu de informar onde que você está criando $_SESSION['nao_autenticado']

Comment: Qual a diferença entre login.php e loginform.php? O que faz a login.php?

Answer (score 1):

Vai ter que usar Ajax. O problema é que quando Clica no botão de Submit a propriedade action do formulário redireciona o submit para mesma pagina, O que da a impressão que fechou o modal. Mais na verdade não.
usa assim:

```
$("form#CriaUmIDparaEle").submit(function(){
let obj = {
url:"login.php",
method: "post",
data: this.serialize(),
complete: function(retorno){
//retorno pode ser echo "1" ou echo json_e();
},
error: function(){
//404, 503 entre outro erros do servidor
}
}
$.ajax(obj);
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! 
Consegui resolver